# why is byte_size of huge number in erlang binary is 1?

Tags: binary, erlang

In erlang, how come byte size of huge number represented as binary is one? I'd thought it should be more?

```
byte_size(<<9999999999994345345645252525254524352425252525245425422222222222222222524524352>>).
1
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not specifying an integer size, so the value narrows to just a single byte, as you can see using the Erlang shell:

```
1> <<9999999999994345345645252525254524352425252525245425422222222222222222524524352>>.
<<"@">>
```

If you specify the proper size, which appears to be 263 bits, you get the right answer:

```
2> byte_size(<<9999999999994345345645252525254524352425252525245425422222222222222222524524352:263>>).
33
```

Comment: Weird, so if I want a binary I have to know how big it is in bits beforehand. Seems like something erlang compiler could do automatically.

Comment: This can't be done by compiler, because number can be unknown at compile time, like `{ok, I} = io:read("Enter I followed by dot"), <<I>>.`

Answer (score 3):

In erlang this data type is a [binary](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id70915). Binary is a sequence of 8-bit (bytes) elements.
You entered only one value into this binary so the resulted value is actually the modulo 256 of this value. If you'll enter only the binary in the shell you'll get:

```
1> <<9999999999994345345645252525254524352425252525245425422222222222222222524524352>>.
<<"@">>
```

`@` ASCII value is 64. Which means that this_long_num modulo 256 = 64.

As you might have already understood, this means that it represents only 1 byte - so this is the reason that the `byte_size/1` of this binary is 1.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert arbitrary integer to its binary representation, you should use [`binary:encode_unsigned`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#encode_unsigned-1)

```
7> byte_size(binary:encode_unsigned(9999999999994345345645252525254524352425252525245425422222222222222222524524352)).
33
```

> ```
> encode_unsigned(Unsigned) -> binary()
> ```
>
> #### Types:
>
> `Unsigned = integer() >= 0` Same as `encode_unsigned(Unsigned, big)`.
>
> ```
> encode_unsigned(Unsigned, Endianness) -> binary()
> ```
>
> #### Types:
>
> `Unsigned = integer() >= 0 Endianness = big | little` Converts a
>   positive integer to the smallest possible representation in a binary
>   digit representation, either big endian or little endian.